# CSS inheritance using auto generated number

Tags: html, css

I have a list of contacts like this:

```
 <div id=\"contact $name\"> 
  Contact 1.
 </div>

 <div id=\"contact $name\"> 
  Contact 2.
 </div>
...and so on
```

`$name` is the name of the contact. I need to do it this way, because somewhere I'm using a javascript for show / hide details for a selected contact so I need a unique id.

I would like to put some style on id `contact`. I'm not very used with CSS but, I assume that there should exist the concept of inheritance for situations like that, right?

I tried to apply a testing style like:

```
#contact { font-size:20px; color:red; }
```

That should apply the style for all id's that have `contact` and if I want some particular style for contact 1, I should use something like `#contact Contact 1 { bla bla bla }`

The problem is that isn't working. What I'm doing wrong there?

EDIT

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  function showHide(elementid){
    if (document.getElementById(elementid).style.display == 'none'){
             document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = '';
    } else {
            document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = 'none';
    }}</script>
```

Comment: It is invalid HTML to have spaces in an id.

Comment: As a side-note: Whitespace is [not allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) in ID. You have to escape the whitespace by a leading backslash like so: `#contact\ Contact\ 1 { ... }`

Comment: @sdsanders, are you sure that this rule is still available in HTML 5?

Comment: Yes. According to the spec: "The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters."

Comment: Starting an attribute value with `\"` isn’t HTML. There is no such thing as “inertance”. Show valid HTML and valid CSS that actually reproduce the issue, and specify what the issue is. If JavaScript is relevant, include the “javascript” tag.

Comment: That html is in a php file. I need to use \ to avoid some conflicts. Anyway, the browser won't see it like `\"`, will see it simple `"`.

Answer (score 4):

It may make more sense to use both an id and a classname in your markup like below:

```
<div class="contact" id=\"$name\"> 
    Contact 1.
</div>

<div class="contact" id=\"$name\"> 
     Contact 2.
</div>
```

And then target by class name in your css like:

```
.contact { font-size:20px; color:red; }
```

Overrides could then be applied based on id like:

```
#contact-1 { color:blue; }
```

That way you can apply your css to all contacts and still show/hide by id with javascript.

Comment: That looks great, but will broke my javascript show/hide script. I just edited my initial post, and I will appreciate a hint for solving that.

Comment: What are you passing as the elementid to your showHide function?

Comment: The div's id `contact $name`.

Comment: As long as your $name variable produces a valid id, this should work.  I created a fiddle showing this: http://jsfiddle.net/xHS6Z/

Answer (score 1):

> That should apply the style for all id's that have contact

An id should be unique to a single contact. If you want something to apply to multiple contacts you should use a class:

```
<div class="contact" id=\"$name\"> 
 Contact 1.
</div>

<div class="contact" id=\"$name\"> 
 Contact 2.
</div>
```

Then you can apply through out:

```
.contact { font-size:20px; color:red; }
```

If you want to apply other unique styles to certain contacts, you should look at how css selectors work:
[CSS Selectors Reference - w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

(You can add styles for odd or even children for example)